# How to do a positional search in a file and find write the lines containing the matching pattern in another file

Tags: shell

The file size is huge and I have to extract only the lines that match a certain location code which is of variable ( varying from 2 bytes to 8 bytes) length.

I cannot use normal grep since that may give undesirable results. When I search for loc cd mas, if I give `grep mas`, it matches with name thomas...

Since this is a fixed length file, I know the position where to search. Is there any command to search at particular position(from 620-628 in my case) and extract the matching lines?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to be a bit more specific on what you want to do and how grep doesn't fit in? Do you mean you want to do the search on fixed character positions on every line? Can you give an example of the input?

Comment: If you're trying to match `mas` but not `thomas`, you may find word boundary anchors useful e.g. `grep '\bmas\b'`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. Ideally, give us a minimal example that we can play with and the output you would like to see from it. What do you mean by "position"? Line numbers? Byte numbers? Letters? Something else? Do you want to search for `loc cd mas` or any of `loc`, `cd`, or `mas`?

Comment: while I was doing a grep I used 
grep '^.\{'620'\}'mas'' file > fileb 
and it gave me the error "grep: RE error 11: Range endpoint too large."
when I am trying 
sed -n '624,629 { /'mas'/p }' file > fileb 
its giving me
sed: command garbled: 623,629 { /mas/p }

Comment: `grep  -n -P  '^.{620}mas'  file` works find for me... You are probably overquoting.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is a good fit for this

```
sed -n '620,628 { /mas/p }'
```

Now it's also possible to have `sed` terminate (so run quicker) after you've read up to the last line you care about; eg

```
sed -n -e '620,628 { /mas/p }' -e '629q'
```

For complete word matches you can change the expression by surrounding it with `\b`

eg

```
sed -n -e '620,628 { /\bmas\b/p }' -e '629q'
```

Now that will match `this contains mas and stuff` but will *not* match `this is a masterful piece of work`.

Comment: while I was doing a grep I used 
grep '^.\{'620'\}'mas'' file > fileb 
and it gave me the error "grep: RE error 11: Range endpoint too large."
when I am trying 
sed -n '624,629 { /'mas'/p }' file > fileb 
its giving me
sed: command garbled: 623,629 { /mas/p }

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
awk '/mas/ && NR >= 620 && NR <= 628' file
```

where

- `NR` (number of record) is line number
- `/mas/` is searched pattern
- default action is to print the line

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
grep -P '^.{620}mas' file
```

If your pattern is changing, you can use variables

```
PAT='mas\b'
grep  -nP "^.{620}$PAT" file
```